# Как получить значения из нескольких QLineEdit

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlineedit, getattr

Есть 20 полей `QLineEdit`.

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать цикл, чтобы получить из них значения и записать в список.

```
    def create_txt(self):
        for line in self.ui.lineEdit_%.text()
            print(line)
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: Пример должен быть минимально-полный, т.е. воспроизводимый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плохая практика не предоставлять пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Как вариант. Поместите в список сами объекты `lineEdit` и по мере надобности делайте то, что вам надо.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.listLineEdit = []                                       # <---
        self.row = 4
        self.column = 5

        btn = QPushButton("Click me", clicked=self.onClick)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)

        for r in range(self.row):
            for c in range(self.column):
                lineEdit = QLineEdit()
                lineEdit.setText("{}:{}".format(r, c))
                self.listLineEdit.append(lineEdit)                    # <---
                self.grid.addWidget(lineEdit, r, c)
        self.grid.addWidget(btn, r+1, 0, 1, self.column)        

    def onClick(self):
        i = 0
        for r in range(self.row):
            for c in range(self.column):
                print(self.listLineEdit[r+c+i].text(), end='; ' )     # <---  
            print()    
            i += self.row

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update:**

Вы можете использовать `setattr()` / `getattr()` как вариант.

Кликните по кнопке, поменяйте `lineEdit-ы` , кликните еще раз.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        flay = QFormLayout(self)
        self.texts = [["name", "какое-то имя"], 
                      ["address", "какой-то адрес"], 
                      ["phone", "какой-то телефон"]]

        for i, text in enumerate(self.texts):
            label = QLabel(text[0]+": ")
            label.setFixedSize(120, 30)
            self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
            flay.addRow(label, self.lineEdit)

            # Атрибут класса создается с помощью setattr ()        
            setattr(self, "lineEdit_{}".format(i+1), self.lineEdit)         # !!!

        flay.addRow(QPushButton("Click me", clicked=self.create_txt)) 

        # использование так:
        #self.lineEdit_1.setText(self.texts[0][1])
        #self.lineEdit_2.setText(self.texts[1][1])
        #self.lineEdit_3.setText(self.texts[2][1])
        # или так:
        for i, _ in enumerate(self.texts):
            obj = getattr(self, "lineEdit_{}".format(i+1))                  # !!!         
            obj.setText(self.texts[i][1])

    def create_txt(self):
#        for line in self.ui.lineEdit_%.text()
#            print(line)

        for i, _ in enumerate(self.texts):
            obj = getattr(self, "lineEdit_{}".format(i+1))                  # !!!
            print(f"{obj.text()}")    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прости за отсутствие примера. у меня по нескольким файлам все распихано. большое спасибо за ответ. а есть ли способ если каждый lineEdit как отдельный объект то есть они lineEdit_1 и далее. извиняюсь за глупый вопрос но никак не могу понять.

Comment: @Ginjou смотрите обновление.